# Where should I put firebase callback code?

Tags: ios, firebase

I have a general organisational question regarding where to place callback code for an observer.  I am still learning about integration of firebase into swift, so go easy on me.

When I have been organising my code I have been placing the observers in the VC from which the read data will be used.  For example, I have a VC which shows a tableview and I have an observer in that VC which populates an array which is used in the tableview.  If any more information is added to the database in that observer location then that observer is ran and the table updated.

This is how I've been structuring my code, but I now have the situation where an observer exists to update a core data element, ie. its not tied to any VC.  In this situation, where should I place the code?

Apologies for the fundamental question, I just want to do it the right way.

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is not only Firebase related but in general about application architecture. There are several ways to approach this issue. You might look up e.g. VIPER as an architecture pattern: https://medium.com/@smalam119/viper-design-pattern-for-ios-application-development-7a9703902af6.
In general you need an observable object outside of your VC, e.g a Singleton which gets injected to your VC's where needed.

Comment: Do you have a situation where your app exists with no viewController? How are you handling interactions with CoreData?

Comment: To handle my core date interactions I have a core data handler which I instantiate in the view controllers I need it in and use it from its instantiations.

Comment: I think you answered your own question. If you have a core data handler, you would also have a firebase handler so the two can interact, right?

Comment: but my core data handler simply has functions in it which I call from a VC.  where would I put the observer code in the core data handler if it is just essentially a collection of functions? (I also have a FB handler and the structure is the same as for the core data handler)

Comment: When responding to a comment, please add the persons name you're responding to with an at glyph, like this @Jay so that user will be notified. Everything in code is pretty much a collection of functions, right? So include those functions within the main viewController so they don't go out of scope. We don't know what  your code is as it was not included in the question but typically, Firebase would be used to store data that at some point is presented to the user so that would require a viewController which makes it the logical place to put it. Are your CD and FB controllers singletons?